# wxPython tree control does not expand to size of its containing panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a frame , and a panel attached to it :

```
panel= wx.Panel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
```

Then I make a tree control widget within this panel :

```
tree = wx.TreeCtrl(panel, 1,style= wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS)
```

I add it to a vertical sizer :

```
vbox1=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
vbox1.Add(panel, 1,  wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
```

but when I run , my treecontrol only occupies corner of the panel , and does not expand to size of its panel.The panel it self is part of another sizer and expands well according to size of its frame.What should I do to make treeControl expand as well?

Answer (score 2):

Add the tree control to a sizer that is within the panel with similar parameters:

```
treeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
treeSizer.Add(tree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
panel.SetSizer(treeSizer)
```